# why does the date php and date unix does not match?

Tags: unix, date, time, php

I have centos server and i rechanged the time to NewYork time by date cmd.
Also i change in php.ini the "date.timezone = "America/New_York""
When i enter the command date in the command shell. i get the real time in new york.
But when I do

> echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

The time isn't right!
I always get 6 hours less then the time in New York.
Please help?
I tried already using date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); in the code with no help.
waiting for a response.
Thanks!
Koren Or

Answer (score 1):

> i rechanged the time to NewYork time by date cmd

The date command doesn't provide a means to change the timezone. You probably set it to the time that it is in new york time, but as whatever timezone it was already set to, so you ended up with the server time being six hours off (odd, it should be five off if it's UTC).

Set the TZ environment variable `export TZ=America/New_York` *before* setting the time with the date command. Having an incorrect server time can lead to serious problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the timezone in your app. What happens when you do this?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: I get :2011-11-23 04:44:09 when the real time is 2011-11-23 10:44:09

Comment: Then it has to be server time/timezone misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

> i change in php.ini the "date.timezone = "America/New_York""

Look, it is very common fault of people who aren't familiar with a formal logic.
Let me show you using a little example:

Suppose you just put some money into your pocket.
I come across and asks you if you got any money in your pocket.
You says "Yes".

But you can't say it for sure!
You can tell for sure only that you *put* it there.
But there can be a hole in the pocket or some thief picked it already or you just confused pockets. 
So, **you have to check it first**, and answer later.

Although it is negligible in the real world, in programming such a behavior become critical!
You can change whatever settings but **you have to verify, if your actions had any effect**
There can be an apache reload issue, or wrong ini.file or some runtime setting overwriting it.

Tl:dr
**Always verify your settings, variables, data - if it *really* contains expected value!**
Do not rely on the fact you changed it somewhere.

Comment: I did verify it. I restart apache and httpd. no effect maked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with not actually setting the timezone correctly on your machine.

First, to verify PHP is using the correct timezone, try the following to see.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s e");
```

That should give you "America/New York" if you have set it correctly in your script.

If so, I would try the procedure discussed [here](http://chrisjean.com/2009/03/03/change-timezone-in-centos/) to change the time on your system and see if that works.

Comment: That worked, but! the hour had changed to "Wed Nov 23 10:49:03 EST 2011" when the real time is "Wed Nov 23 16:49:53 CET 2011"

Comment: @user692601 I believe you will need to set your system time again now that you have changed the timezone. You can do that with the "date" command. Set it to the correct time in whatever timezone you picked.

Comment: @user692601 This whole issues seems to be stemming from the usage of CET timezone (which is +6 hours relative to New York time). The real time that you displayed *is* the correct time, but NOT for the CET timezone as shown. You need to make sure that your timezone is set properly and that your system time is the correct time for that zone.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just guessing here but do you restarted your apache server?